# Visual representation of complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am doing an exercise on stating whether a set is open, closed, its interior, boundary, etc in the complex plane and i have been relying on my geometric intuition and drawing diagrams in order to get solutions. Now i have arrived at this exression:

$F = \{z: z^3-2z^2+5z-4 = 0\} $ and i got to thinking there isn't really a simple geometric picture for this set is there? I say this because i have to take into account the fact that complex values are composed of two components so i can't get away with for instance trying to draw a curve such as $y = x^3$ which woukd have been my first thought. So how should i approach this? All that comes to mind is that since the set is equal to a fixed value this means that it is some sort of line and as such it means the interior is emoty,  the boundary is the line, it is a closed set.

Comment: $z=1$ is a solution since $1-2+5-4=0$ then it's easy enough to pull out a quadratic which factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to help visualize things, just think of the it as two curves, by writing $z=a+bi$, and looking at the real and imaginary parts:
$$-4 + 5 a - 2 a^2 + a^3 + 2 b^2 - 3 a b^2 = 0$$
$$5 b - 4 a b + 3 a^2 b - b^3=0$$
 Each one describes a curve in $\mathbb R^2$, so that your complex curve is actually two real curves.

These two curves can only intersect at three points, as shown below:

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ [image]

Comment: very nice, but, I wonder, how to do this by hand :) I'm guessing staying complex is a better bet. Of course, your response is totally appropriate for the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's a complex polynomial of degree 3, for which you know there must be 3 solutions. The only thing you have to check is, if any roots are degenerate (multiple). The answer is a set of discrete points in the complex plane.